# convert character into a time object with millisecond level in r

Tags: r, datetime, time, posixct

I have a full list of time stamps, named 'time'.

typeof(time) is character, time[1:5] is

```
c('20151122224357714','20151122225351332' , '20151122230112066', '20151122231644405', '20151122233024263')
```

I want to convert this UTC time format to U.S. CST time with the millisecond level.

My current code is:

```
 timeDate(time[1:5], format = "%Y%m%d%H:%M:%OS", FinCenter = America/Chicago")
```

It turned out to be really messed up, and the results are wrong.

Thank you so much if someone could help.

Comment: `timeDate()`?  That function didn't come with my base R install, but I bet you could just remove the `:` since they aren't in the strings and do `format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%OS"`

Comment: Installed `timeDate` package and tried without the colons and it works. Closing as typo.

Comment: @RichScriven, thank you, I think you are right. But how can i include the millisecond level of precision. It seems that the precision is always to the second level. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%OS` input format expects a decimal place, so add one in then check what you get:

```
x <- c('20151122224357714','20151122225351332',
       '20151122230112066', '20151122231644405', '20151122233024263')

out <- as.POSIXct(sub("^(\\d{14})", "\\1.", x), format="%Y%m%d%H%M%OS", tz="UTC")

# check that the milliseconds are there:
format(out, "%F %H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "2015-11-22 22:43:57.713" "2015-11-22 22:53:51.332"
#[3] "2015-11-22 23:01:12.065" "2015-11-22 23:16:44.404"
#[5] "2015-11-22 23:30:24.263"

# note that the rounding is funny when printed due to floating point precision,
# but the data is exact
dput(out)
#structure(c(1448232237.714, 1448232831.332, 1448233272.066, 1448234204.405, 
#1448235024.263), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my approach

```
library(lubridate)
test <- c('20151122224357714','20151122225351332' , '20151122230112066', '20151122231644405', '20151122233024263')
time <- as.POSIXct(test, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tz = "America/Chicago")
millis <- substr(test, 15, 17)
options(digits.secs = 3)
result <- time+milliseconds(as.numeric(millis))

result
```

"2015-11-22 22:43:57.713 CST" "2015-11-22 22:53:51.332 CST" "2015-11-22 23:01:12.065 CST" "2015-11-22 23:16:44.404 CST" "2015-11-22 23:30:24.263 CST"